# How to create a custom request using node-soap

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, soap, wsdl

This is the message I need to send to `wsdl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>    
<soapenv:Envelope 
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <tem:ConsultarCreditos>
             <tem:usuario>DEMO010233001</tem:usuario>
             <tem:password>Pruebas1a$</tem:password>
          </tem:ConsultarCreditos>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have this code:

```
const wsdlOptions = {
    envelopeKey: "soapenv"
};
soap.createClient(URL, wsdlOptions, function(err, client) {
    const args = {
        _xml: '<tem:ConsultarCreditos><tem:usuario> DEMO010233001 </tem:usuario><tem:password>Pruebas1a$</tem:password></tem:ConsultarCreditos>',
    }
    client.ConsultarCreditos(args, function(err, result, raw, soapHeader) {
        console.log('last request: ', client.lastRequest)
    });

});
```

Which results this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
    xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" 
    xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tem:ConsultarCreditos>
            <tem:usuario>DEMO010233001</tem:usuario>
            <tem:password>Pruebas1a$</tem:password>
        </tem:ConsultarCreditos>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to change the attributes of the tag `soapenv:Envelope` but I don't know how to do that.

I just need these attributes:

```
> xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
> xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

May be this is no the best solution but it works for me.
In the callback createCliete override the property `client.wsdl.xmlnsInEnvelope` whit the xmlns that i want, `client.wsdl.xmlnsInEnvelope = 'xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"';`

The complete code:

```
    soap.createClient(URL, wsdlOptions, function(err, client) {
        client.wsdl.xmlnsInEnvelope = 'xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"';
        const args = {
            _xml: '<tem:ConsultarCreditos><tem:usuario> DEMO010233001 </tem:usuario><tem:password>Pruebas1a$</tem:password></tem:ConsultarCreditos>',
        }
        client.ConsultarCreditos(args, function(err, result, raw, soapHeader) {
            console.log('last request: ', client.lastRequest)
        });

    });
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tem:ConsultarCreditos>
            <tem:usuario>DEMO010233001</tem:usuario>
            <tem:password>Pruebas1a$</tem:password>
        </tem:ConsultarCreditos>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved the day.